# Fixing Graphserver warning osmdb has no edges

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis, openstreetmap, routing

I have some shapefiles data that I'm trying to import in [graphserver](http://graphserver.github.com/graphserver/). I'm doing:

```
gs_osmdb_compile output3.osm output3.osmdb
```

And the result is: `WARNING: osmdb has no edges!`.

I'm using a shapefile that may not be ready for import. I'm converting it to OSM, then I'm trying to import it using `gs_osmdb_compile`. I guess they are related to the [v.net](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/v.net.html) function in GRASS, but I'm not sure to understand what should be the end result.